# Как использовать $this->module в статических методах?

Tags: yii2

собственно в своем расширении пытаюсь реализовать подключение либо базы через миграцию либо если у пользователя есть своя таблица для настроек то таблицу пользователя собственно вот код

```
public static function tableName()
{
    $module=self::module;
    if(empty($module->modelDb)){
        return '{{%menu_table}}';
    }else{
        return $module->dbName->name;
    }
}
```

вот сам проект на [гите](https://github.com/Sirgalas/yii2-wordperss-menu/blob/master/models/Menu.php) но вываливается ошибка

> Undefined class constant

'module'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$module = MyModuleClass::getInstance();
```